# Looking to return a number based on the date that is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I am looking to try and work out how to get a return from a table, depending on what it is that you enter. As an example I have included an image of how the table might look. I have a range of 5 agents who depending on the week, they would have a different number showing against their name (which is the shift they would be working). I need it so that I select the name of the agent, the date I am looking to find the information for, and this would then return the number that I need.

In the example there is a smaller table which shows that I am looking for information on Agent 4, and the date I am looking for is April 2nd. Looking at the table for the week commencing 29th March, which April 2nd falls in, this would return the number 3. I can't work out how to get it to return the number 3 to me so any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: It seems you forgot to include the actual table.

Comment: Remember that a date is stored as a floating-point number, and the the >, <, >= and <= operators work against numbers.

Comment: `=WEEKNUM(date,1)` returns a week number for the year in date (`ISOWEEKNUM()` may be even more interesting). `=WEEKDAY(date,2)` will return a number indicating how far into the week the day is, `=TEXT(date,"dddd")` will show you the weekday as text, with "ddd" as three letters, with "dd" as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For the table shown you can use (in C11):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$K$6,MATCH($A$11,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH($B$11,$B$1:$K$1))
```

Also you can calculate the number from the rule:

```
=MOD((WEEKNUM($B$11,15)+4)+MATCH($A$11,$A$2:$A$6),5)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula, it uses `XLOOKUP()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C11</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(A11,A2:A6,XLOOKUP(B11,B1:K1,B2:K6,,-1))
```

---

Another alternative using `SUM()` & `WEEKNUM()`

[image]

---

```
=SUM((WEEKNUM(B11,15)=WEEKNUM(+B1:K1,15))*(A11=A2:A6)*B2:K6)
```

---

To explain the phenomenon of using `+` in `WEEKNUM()` function, I have explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77595703/8162520)**

---